# Closure and preclosures inducing the same topology

Tags: general-topology

One can show that every closure operator $\mathbf c: \wp X \to \wp X$ satisfying [Kuratowski's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms), induces a topology on $X$, namely the family of subsets of $X$ whose complements are stable under $\mathbf c$; the mapping $\mathfrak X$ assigning to each Kuratowski closure the associated topology is actually a bijection, and its inverse is given by

$$\mathfrak{X}^{-1}[\tau](A) = \bigcap_{B\in (A^\uparrow \cap\ \mathbf n_\wp\tau)}B, \tag1$$

where $A^\uparrow$ indicates the upset of $A$, i.e. the family of all subsets of $X$ that contain $A$, and $\mathbf n_\wp\tau$ is the family of all complements of sets in $\tau$.

The same is true for *preclosure* operators $\check{\mathbf c}: \wp X \to \wp X$, i.e. a closure operator satisfying all four of Kuratowski's axioms *but* the idempotency requirement $\mathbf c^2 = \mathbf c$, meaning that the mapping $\mathfrak X$ can be extended to a mapping $\mathfrak X^\star$ acting on preclosures; but $\mathfrak X^\star$ will not be a bijection anymore, meaning that for any given topology $\tau$ there may be one or more preclosures $\check{\mathbf c}$ inducing it, besides the Kuratowski closure defined in $(1)$.

> Can the family of all preclosures inducing the same topology be characterized someway, maybe assuming the topology to satisfy special requirements (separability, countability, etc.)?

Since $\check{\mathbf c}$ is isotonic, i.e. $A \subseteq B$ implies $\check{\mathbf c}(A) \subseteq \check{\mathbf c}(B)$, it follows that $\check{\mathbf c}(A) \subseteq \mathbf c(A)$ for all $A \in \wp X$, where $\mathbf c:= \mathfrak X^{-1}[\mathfrak X^\star[\check{\mathbf c}]]$ is the Kuratowski closure inducing the same topology as $\check{\mathbf c}$. Iterating, we have a chain of inclusion
$$\varnothing \subseteq A \subseteq \check{\mathbf c}(A) \subseteq \check{\mathbf c}^2(A) \subseteq \dots  \subseteq \mathbf c(A).$$
I expect this chain of inclusion to be infinite in general, and maybe collapse to a finite chain in the special cases where the topology satisfies particular properties. If this is the case, then the stable set must coincide with the closure $\mathbf c(A)$.

> What are (necessary and) sufficient conditions on a topology $\tau$ such that there is $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $\check{\mathbf c}^{n+1} = \check{\mathbf c}^n$ for all possible preclosures $\check{\mathbf c}$ inducing $\tau$?

Comment: In general you could only get a stable closure at some infinite cardinal or ordinal.

Comment: I just came across this question and two or three other questions of yours on closure operators, this being moments after after I upvoted your answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3521100/13130) when I happened to click on your username to see what kinds of questions/answers you've posted (apparently because I have nothing better to do right now . . .). I don't know if anything in my lengthy 3-part answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780) would be of interest to you, but I thought I'd point it out in case you had missed it.

Comment: The answer you linked is incredibly interesting; were I a member of that stack community I would certainly upvote it in all its parts. Thank you!

Comment: PS If you care enough to post a similar answer here I would be happy to upvote and accept it.

Comment: At the moment (as in next few days at least) I don't really have time to think enough about what you're specifically asking to say any meaningful, but I'll try to remember to return and look at this question at some later time.